# MailChimp Subscriber Form not valid HTML5 w3c validation

Tags: html, validation, mailchimp

I want to use mailchimp for my blog in blogger platform.
but I get not valid HTML5 when I put the mailchimp subscriber form code. the url in input tag have  &, and its was replaced with & , but its not work in w3c validation.

This is my code :

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="http://blogspot.us7.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post-json?u=f1600d5083d5549617f6ab529&amp;id=d318678b58&amp;c=?" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
      <label for="mce-EMAIL">E-mail Newsletter Signup</label>
      <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>

      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_58abcfa203271a9db312e69fc_ee0af79b60" value=""></div>

      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </form>

    <div id="notification_container"></div>
</div>
```

this code is valid at [here](http://blackcyber99.googlecode.com/svn/Priv/mailchimp/index.html) 
but when I put that code in my blog its not valid. This is my blog : [www.devilzart.com](http://www.devilzart.com)
whats wrong with my blog coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete `novalidate` from tag `form`.